# How do I shorten a plot line in highcahrts that was added with the addPlotLine method?

Tags: highcharts

I have a dotted plotline that I added with the addPlotLine method that I need shortened so that it is closer to the xAxis line. Right now it looks like this [image]

,but I need those dotted lines shortened so it looks like this
[image]

This is the method I used for adding the plotline
this.yAxis[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEd7Q.png).addPlotLine({
value: sum2 / y2Data.length,
dashStyle: 'longdash',
label: {
text:  formatter.format(Math.round(sum2 / y2Data.length)),
x: -20
}
});
The "value" object tells us where along the y axis tells us where along the y axis the line goes. Anyway I can tell it where along the x axis the line should start. For example 0 would be where the horizontal line is and -.5 would be just to the left around where I want it?

Answer (score 0):

Plotlines in Highcharts by definition occupy all axis space. To achieve what you want, you can modify the created SVG element:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
          xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
          plotLines = yAxis.plotLinesAndBands;

        if (!plotLines[0]) {
          yAxis.addPlotLine({
            value: 2.5,
            dashStyle: 'longdash'
          });
        }

        const plotLineEl = plotLines[0].svgElem;
        // [[M, x, y], [L, x, y]]
        plotLineEl.pathArray[0][1] = xAxis.toPixels(0.5);

        plotLineEl.attr({
          d: plotLineEl.pathArray
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8rtm5p7o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

---

or use `renderer` to create a custom one:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const chart = this,
          xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
          x1 = xAxis.toPixels(1),
          x2 = xAxis.toPixels(3),
          y = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(2.5);

        if (!chart.customPath) {
          chart.customPath = chart.renderer.path()
            .attr({
              'stroke-width': 1,
              stroke: '#ff00ff',
              dashstyle: 'longdash'
            })
            .add();
        }

        chart.customPath.attr({
          d: ['M', x1, y, 'L', x2, y]
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aj8vrsn4/

**API Refererence:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path