# Hide plot line in chart background

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a radial column chart and I'd like to make the plot line "invisible" in the chart background, but show up on top of the chart series. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe with z-index? I'm open to other solutions not using the plot line setting. Thank you!

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atmjwqe3/40/

```js
yAxis: {
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  lineWidth: 0,
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotLines: [{
    color: 'black',
    value: 40,
    width: 3,
    zIndex: 100
  }]
}
```

Current chart output:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Do you want to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k4or6jb1/ ? (It is done by `groupPadding: 0`)

Comment: Alternatively, you can take a look at the following topic where you will find the information about overwriting the plotLines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75892939/how-do-i-shorten-a-plot-line-in-highcahrts-that-was-added-with-the-addplotline-m

Comment: Thanks for the response @magdalena! Yeah, my concern is that if I use `groupPadding` (or `pointWidth`) the plot line will extend the entire axis width. So it looks like I will need to overwrite the plotLines-- thx for the link.